# How to switch between widgets using forward and back buttons in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Need help with code. I have containers (buttons) with date numbers and days of the week (this is `MyDayPicker`) and at the top of the button in the form of arrow icons. I need to be able to switch back and forth among the containers with dates (`MyDayPicker`) with the help of the arrow buttons. I think that this can be done using `AnimatedSwitcher`, but maybe I'm wrong. What is the solution to this problem, I will be grateful if you help me?

**body**

```
 Row(
     children: [
        GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {},
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
               constants.Assets.arrowLeftSmall,
               width: 8.5,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 25),
            const Text(
                '1 May - 2022',
                style: constants.Styles.smallerHeavyTextStyleWhite,
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 25),
            GestureDetector( 
            onTap: () {},
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
                 constants.Assets.arrowRight,
            ),
         ),
     ],
  ),
 MyDayPicker(
   onChanged: (val) {
          if (val == -1) {
             setState(() {
                 _isDaySchedule = false;
                 _dayNum = 0;
             });
             return;
          }
          setState(() {
             _isDaySchedule = true;
             _dayNum = val;
          });
         },
          size: size,
   ),
```

**MyDayPicker**

```
class MyDayPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color activeColor;
  final Size size;
  final Function(int) onChanged;

  const MyDayPicker({
    Key? key,
    required this.size,
    required this.onChanged,
    this.activeColor = constants.Colors.purpleMain,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyDayPicker> createState() => _MyDayPicker();
}

class _MyDayPicker extends State<MyDayPicker> {
  int selectedDay = -1;

  void selectDay(int dayPos) {
    setState(() {
      if (dayPos == selectedDay) {
        selectedDay = -1;
        widget.onChanged(selectedDay);
        return;
      }
      selectedDay = dayPos;
      widget.onChanged(selectedDay);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: UiSize.getWidth(15, widget.size),
                  ),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => selectDay(i),
                    child: _dayPicker(i + 1, _days[i]),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _dayPicker(int day, String dayName) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      width: UiSize.getWidth(30, widget.size),
      height: UiSize.getHeight(50, widget.size),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.5),
        color: constants.Colors.purpleXDark.withOpacity(0.6),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: UiSize.getHeight(32, widget.size),
            width: UiSize.getWidth(30, widget.size),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.5),
              color: day - 1 == selectedDay
                  ? widget.activeColor
                  : constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.15),
            ),
            child: Text(
              '$day',
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: TextSize.textSmall,
                fontFamily: FontFamily.AvenirHeavy,
                color: constants.Colors.white,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            dayName,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: TextSize.textXxxTiny,
              fontFamily: FontFamily.AvenirMedium,
              color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  final List<String> _days = const [
    'SUN',
    'MON',
    'TUE',
    'WED',
    'THU',
    'FRI',
    'SAT',
  ];
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what the problem was? Sure, you can use AnimatedSwitcher, or AnimatedContainer, or any widget that accepts a widget as a child parameter actually. Keep your 'changing widgets' in a list and keep the index value in your class. Then ,show only the list[index] element in page. Every time user taps back and forth change the index value.

Comment: Okay, I'll try with